# Python NLTK : Extract lexical head item from Stanford dependency parsed result

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I have a sentence and i want to extract lexical head item, i could do the dependency parsing using Stanford NLP library.

**How can i extract main head head in a sentence?**

In the case of the sentence `Download and share this tool`, the head would be `Download`.

I've tried the following:

```
 def get_head_word(text):
     standepparse=StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar='/home/stanford_resource/stanford-parser-full-2014-06-16/stanford-parser.jar',path_to_models_jar='/home/stanford_resource/stanford-parser-full-2014-06-16/stanford-parser-3.4-models.jar',model_path='/home/stanford_resource/stanford-parser-full-2014-06-16/stanford-parser-3.4-models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz')
     parsetree=standepparse.raw_parse(text)
     p_tree=list(parsetree)[0]
     print p_tree.to_dot()

 text = 'Download and share this tool'
 get_head_word(text)


output:

digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]

0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 1 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (Download)"]
1 -> 2 [label="cc"]
1 -> 3 [label="conj"]
1 -> 5 [label="dobj"]
2 [label="2 (and)"]
3 [label="3 (share)"]
4 [label="4 (this)"]
5 [label="5 (software)"]
5 -> 4 [label="det"]
}
```

Comment: Is it enough :

    `for n in p_tree.nodes.values():  
        if n['head']==0:  
            print n['word'],n['head']`

Comment: Could you rephrase your question a little? What do you mean by "download"?

Comment: @alvas 
I want to extract lexical head item. In sentence mentioned, (if I am correct) the head item is 'download'.
So for another sentence `we love python`, the lexical head item would be `love`.

Comment: Oh, then you will only need to find the first node after "None->root" which will give you the sentence head. `next(n for n in p_tree.node_values() if n['head'] == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the dependency head of sentence, simply look for nodes that whose `head` values points to the `root` node. In `NLTK` API to [DependencyGraph](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.py), you can easily look for the node that its head points to the 1st index of the dictionary.

Do note that in dependency parsing unlike typical chomsky normal form / CFG parse trees there might be more than one head to the dependency parse.

But since you're casting the dependency output into a Tree structure, you can do the following:

```
tree_head = next(n for n in p_tree.node_values() if n['head'] == 1)
```

But do note that linguistically, the head in the sentence`Download and share this tool` should be `Download` **and** `share`. But computationally a tree is hierarchical and a normal-form tree would have `ROOT->Download->and->share` but some parsers might produce this tree too: `ROOT->and->Download;share`